# Service which returns multiple promises based on data from single HTTP request

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I wish to implement a service which has the following features:

- Performs a HTTP request to a given resource only once.
- Provides two exported functions, each of which return a promise, where the promise is resolved based on data from the one-time HTTP call.

The two functions shall exist to provide different representations of the fetched data.

The outline of my service so far is as follows:

```
angular.module('someApp')
.service('someService', function ($http) {

    var httpPromise = $http.get('/some/endpoint/').then(
            function(response) {
                // HTTP response data is processed
            });

    this.getSomePromise = function() {
        // Return a promise which is resolved using one representation of HTTP response
    }

    this.getAnotherPromise = function() {
        // Return a promise which is resolved using another representation of HTTP response
    }

});
```

If there was only the need for one 'getter' function then clearly I could simply have returned the `httpPromise`.

What is the appropriate way to implement the interface as shown? Is it possible for two or more consumers to call `.then()` on the same promise, in which case I could merely return `httpPromise.then(function(){...modify data...})` from both functions? Or, in this scenario would it be necessary to create a new promise (using `$q.defer()`) and resolve it somehow based on a cache object which holds the HTTP response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create two promises, using chaining, on the http promise:

```
var httpPromise = $http.get('/some/endpoint/');

var firstPromise = httpPromise.then(function(response) {
    return firstTransformation(response.data);
});

var secondPromise = httpPromise.then(function(response) {
    return secondTransformation(response.data);
});

this.getSomePromise = function() {
    return firstPromise;
}

this.getAnotherPromise = function() {
    return secondPromise;
}
```

Comment: Thank you greatly for the answer! I'm going to attempt this now, though I'm puzzled about how this works. From my understanding this isn't 'chaining' as such since we're not actually calling `then()` on a promise returned from a subsequent `then()` call; instead we're calling `then()` twice on a given promise object. For this to work, does the promise internally maintain a list of callbacks to call?

Comment: Ah! I've just scanned through https://promisesaplus.com/ and noticed this point: `then may be called multiple times on the same promise` and `If/when promise is fulfilled, all respective onFulfilled callbacks must execute in the order of their originating calls to then`. So I understand now that being able to call `then()` multiple times with different callbacks is part of the promise contract. That's the key thing. Unless I've glossed over too much, a lot of documentation doesn't seem to explicitly state this. Again, thank you greatly for the answer and help.